# Graphhopper cannot find symbol method create(long,XMLStreamReader) iOS

Tags: java, ios, maven, graphhopper

Here is the log file for cannot find symbol method create(long,XMLStreamReader) for Graphhoper for ios.

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/tree/master/graphhopper-ios-sample

Runnning:
     ./graphhopper.sh build

```
 Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/3.0.3/trove4j-3.0.3.jar (2465 KB at 876.0 KB/sec)
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce (enforce-maven) @ graphhopper ---
 [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ graphhopper ---
   [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
   [INFO] Copying 2 resources
   [INFO] Copying 42 resources
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ graphhopper ---

   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
   [INFO] Compiling 206 source files to /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/target/classes
   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMInputFile.java:[223,46] error: cannot find symbol
   [ERROR]   symbol:   method create(long,XMLStreamReader)
   location: class OSMNode
   /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMInputFile.java:[230,41] error: cannot find symbol
   [ERROR]   symbol:   method create(long,XMLStreamReader)
   location: class OSMWay
   /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMInputFile.java:[234,46] error: cannot find symbol
  [INFO] 3 errors 
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Reactor Summary:
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] GraphHopper Parent Project ......................... SUCCESS [  2.243 s]
  [INFO] GraphHopper Tools LGPL licensed .................... SUCCESS [ 16.804 s]
  [INFO] GraphHopper ........................................ FAILURE [ 15.722 s]
  [INFO] GraphHopper Tools .................................. SKIPPED
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 35.209 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-17T01:07:57-08:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/133M
  [INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project graphhopper: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
  [ERROR] /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMInputFile.java:[223,46] error: cannot find symbol
  [ERROR] symbol:   method create(long,XMLStreamReader)
  [ERROR] location: class OSMNode
  [ERROR] /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMInputFile.java:[230,41] error: cannot find symbol
  [ERROR] symbol:   method create(long,XMLStreamReader)
  [ERROR] location: class OSMWay
  [ERROR] /Users/user/Desktop/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/graphhopper/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/OSMInputFile.java:[234,46] error: cannot find symbol
  [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR]
```

Comment: Which branch are you using? Also you could create an entry in our forum and link here as not all contributors are listening on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Karussell I am using final branch. Also the pom.xml files have errors. I had to clean manually.

Comment: Okay, this is now answered here: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios/issues/12